# How do I get text bounding box drawn with pgmagick

Tags: imagemagick, graphicsmagick, pgmagick

I successfully draw some text on an image by pgmagick:

```
from pgmagick.api import Image
img = Image((300, 200))
img.annotate('Hello World')
img.write('helloworld.png')
```

but how to get the bounding box of text? Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know anything about `pgmagick` but maybe it will help if I show you a couple of things you can do at the command line with **ImageMagick**.

**Option 1**

Use `label` to create a canvas just big enough for the desired text and then ask **ImageMagick** how big that canvas's geometry is:

```
convert label:"Hello world" -format %G info:
62x15
```

So, "Hello world" in the default font size is 62 pixels wide and 15 pixels high.

**Option 2**

Or, use `-annotate` as you did, and then ask **ImageMagick** how big that would be if you trimmed the excess space around it:

```
convert -size 300x200 xc:red -annotate +10+20 "Hello world" -format %@ info:
61x8+10+12
```

**Option 3**

Create the canvas and annotate it, then trim it and get the size:

```
convert -size 300x200 xc:red -annotate +10+20 "Hello world" -trim info:
xc:red XC 61x8 300x200+10+12 16-bit sRGB 0.000u 0:00.000
```

**Option 4**

Create canvas, annotate, trim, save and then get dimensions of result:

```
convert -size 300x200 xc:red -annotate +10+20 "Hello world" -trim result.png

identify result.png
result.png PNG 61x8 300x200+10+12 16-bit sRGB 887B 0.000u 0:00.000
```

Maybe (hopefully) you can adapt one of these to `pgmagick`.